# How do I make HeadlessUI compatible with Webpack?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-dev-server, es6-modules, headless-ui

My screen goes blank whenever I uncomment a HeadlessUI component.

I receive the following error:

'Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.'

After a day of researching, I've come to the conclusion it's an ESM related issue through various forums but failed to get anything to work.

How can I fix this (if I even can)?

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  output: {
    filename: "index.bundle.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|esm)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
    }),
  ],
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sesame-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.5.0",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.5",
    "axios": "^0.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^6.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "css-loader": "^6.6.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.5.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "postcss": "^8.4.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23",
    "webpack": "^5.69.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```